# Google app script to check if an email exists in domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

We have Gsuite for education and email addresses are created by a separate department and our department hands out tickets to registered students, sometimes students can bring their friends and fake emails with our school's domain, it takes more than 3 hours to get email verification from the Registration department, we were thinking of having a google script web app where we could type in the email address and it would tell us if its real or fake. The emails should be checked on our domain only.
We have checked the `User Class` and it only can get the current user's email address only `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`
is there a function or class that can help us achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, this is possible wiht the [Admin directory API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory).

The documentation provides a sample code that does exactly what you want - list all users of your domain:

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Adapt the code by replacing `'example.com'` through your domain name, and if you want to list ALL students, remove the line `maxResults: 100,`.

> Keep in mind that `Admin directory API` is an [Advanced Google
>   Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) and needs to be [enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) from the Script Editor UI
>   through `Resources->Advanced Google Services...`.

Comment: Thanks, let me test it out, one thing...`orderBy: 'givenName',` what does `givenName` supposed to be?

Comment: It is the first name, you can also order by `familyName` or `email`, as specified in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list

Comment: Can I use google java sdk to check if user is a gsuite user or not?

Comment: The AdminDirectory API only allows to check either a user is a part of your domain. If he is -it automatically means that he is GSuite user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a slightly different way based on the solution provided by @ziganotschka. Thank you!

Here's my solution...

After checking each user in my list of emails, the errors are captured in an array that is logged at the end. Approx. 500 emails checked in two minutes.

```
function verifyEmails() {

  // Collects Sheet Data (Emails) and creates arrays
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.openById(your_sheet_ID).getSheetByName(your_sheet_name);
  var firstRow = 2;
  var emailData = master.getRange('C' + firstRow + ':C').getValues();
  var invalidArray = [];

  // Loops through email array and logs invalid emails
  emailData.forEach(array => {

    try {
      var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(array);
    }
    catch (e) {
      invalidArray.push(array);
    }

  });

  console.log(invalidArray);

}
```

Of course, users will want to replace `your_sheet_ID` and `your_sheet_name` with your appropriate values.